# Auto identify Height in dotdotdot plugins

Tags: jquery, dotdotdot, jquery-dotdotdot

How to set auto height from css in `jquery dotdotdot` plugins.

note: I use [dotdotdot](https://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugins.

For Example:

```css
.dot{
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
}


.paragraph-1{
 height: 100px;
 background-color: tomato
}

.paragraph-2{
 height: 50px;
 background-color: lightblue
}


.paragraph-3{
 height: 200px;
 background-color: yellow

}
```

```html
<div>
 <p class="dot paragraph-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, munere tamquam propriae an pro, sit dicam denique an, eum nonumes electram te. Eum laudem denique fierent ne, admodum suscipit nam in. Ne pri movet saepe periculis. Sea ancillae noluisse no.</p>

 <p class="dot paragraph-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, munere tamquam propriae an pro, sit dicam denique an, eum nonumes electram te. Eum laudem denique fierent ne, admodum suscipit nam in. Ne pri movet saepe periculis. Sea ancillae noluisse no.</p>

 <p class="dot paragraph-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, munere tamquam propriae an pro, sit dicam denique an, eum nonumes electram te. Eum laudem denique fierent ne, admodum suscipit nam in. Ne pri movet saepe periculis. Sea ancillae noluisse no.

 Ipsum legendos concludaturque cu mel, iudico eligendi vel at, prima partem democritum et pro. Ne dolor ocurreret eos, in sea periculis aliquando. Mei ex vitae nostrum pertinacia. An utroque nominati liberavisse eos, postea constituto duo ne. Ea vide doctus quo, ceteros referrentur contentiones an sit. Eu causae feugiat pertinacia has.

 Duo possit integre petentium cu. At dicat suavitate eum, legere commune ius an. Qui in accusam ullamcorper. Labores voluptatum id eos. Ne oratio inermis volumus duo, nec ei illum impetus.

 Et qui dictas vivendum, ad ius dicit denique, partem populo apeirian cum at. Ad vix odio suscipiantur. In euismod efficiendi mei, ut impetus sapientem vulputate usu, iudico persius mandamus sed ex. Vis at velit percipit, eum ex vitae explicari pertinacia.</p>

</div>
```

#### I want to run ‍‍‍this code for all elements

```
$('.dot').dotdotdot();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$('.dot').each(function () {
    let dot_height = $(this).height();
    $(this).dotdotdot({
        height: dot_height,
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your first answer. It's always helpful if you explain your answer and how it works rather than just posting code. This will help those looking for answers get a better understanding.